# what is faster... DBMS_XMLDOM vs appendchildxml

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I need to create a very large xml file (up to 100k nodes) in PL-SQL.
Which way is faster ? DBMS_XMLDOM or appendchildxml ?

Comment: Oracle 11g - we are finding that appendchildxml performance degrades fairly rapidly as the number of sibling nodes increase. We have improved performance significantly by minimising the number of inserts. We do this by assembling each node and all it's children in a small staging document and then appending the staging document into the main document via appendchildxml, rather than doing everything in the target "growing" document (we are going to be looking at DOM shortly to try to increase performance further if possible - I will update with our findings when we have them)

Answer (score 1):

We likewise use Oracle 11g R2, and we create an XML document for reporting purposes. The entire process ie.  **retrieval** from the database, **restructuring** of the data and **assembly** the output XML document, was taking 130 seconds.

We assumed that the first phase, ie. the **retrieval**, would probably be taking the bulk of the time so we optimised this and reduced the total time by 40 seconds down to around 90 seconds.

We were surprised that it still remained "slow" - so we investigated the **restructuring** and **assembly** phases, and to our surprise found that the bulk of the time was being taken by the **assembly** phase, with each appendchildxml statement getting successively slower as the document grew.

We therefore stripped out the *appendchildxml* and replaced it entirely with dbms_xmldom code.

Happily, this change reduced the entire process to only 9 seconds ie. an order of magnitude reduction.

Based on this and other performance gains we have seen on the database with dbms_xmldom I would recommend using dbms_xmldom.